# HSQLDB - link several sequences for several columns of the table

Tags: sql, hsqldb

I would like to link several sequences for generating default values for several columns of a table.

For example:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq1 START WITH 1;
CREATE SEQUENCE seq2 START WITH 1;
CREATE TABLE mytable (rid int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS SEQUENCE seq1 PRIMARY KEY, p63 int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS SEQUENCE seq2)
```

Unfortunately, an error is occured: "identity definition not allowed"

In Postgresql is working.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first use of the sequence is allowed. You can write a BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER to insert sequence values into the second column.

Comment: Thanks for your response. With PostgreSQL this kind of queries is allowed. I've no choice ... at this time

Answer (score 1):

Having the same issue, I came upon this post. I used another workaround :

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq1 START WITH 1;
CREATE SEQUENCE seq2 START WITH 1;

CREATE TABLE mytable (
    rid int DEFAULT nextval('seq1') NOT NULL,
    p63 int NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER p63 SET DEFAULT NEXTVAL('seq2');
```

Altering the `p63` column after table creation made possible to use the `seq2` sequence while it was not accepted when creating the table.